Jenkins Generic Webhook Trigger plugin replaces ${branchName} with literal String after a run
I have a problem with the Generic Webhook Trigger plugin in Jenkins where the variable ${branchName} is not resolved as expected after the first pipeline run. Instead, the value is hard-coded and remains the same for all subsequent builds. Here is an excerpt from my Jenkinsfile:
triggers {
    GenericTrigger(
      genericVariables: [
        [key: "actorId", value: '$.actor.id'],
        [key: "branchName", value: '$.pullRequest.fromRef.displayId'],
        ...
      ],
      causeString: "Triggered on ${branchName}",

In the 'Cause' field in the Jenkins GUI, I inserted 'Triggered on ${branchName}' which works on the first run. After that first run the literal string of the branch name (e.g. Triggered on test/test-123-test-test) is saved and displayed instead of the placeholder ${branchName}. This leads to the behaviour that the reason for the previously run pipeline is specified as the trigger for the next pipeline. I want the actual name of the branch to be displayed dynamically for each trigger.
So far I have tried to use only the 'Cause' field in the Jenkins GUI. This worked on the first run, but I replaced the 'Cause' field with 'Generic Cause'.
Have any of you already had a similar problem or a solution to my problem?
Thank you in advance.

Try causeString: 'Triggered on $branchName'.

Unfortunately, this does not work either. With this notation, the variable $branchName is no longer interpreted at all and the pipeline only shows Triggerd on $branchName
